# "browser.status" throws Timeout::Error for chrome browser

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any alternative way to get chrome browser status other than using browser.status? 
Because it throws "Timeout::Error" intermittently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue using begin - rescue block as below.

```
  begin
    timeout(720) do
      x = @browser.status
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
      debug("Timeout waiting for browser loading")
  end
```